# How do I selectivly print elements on a page

Tags: asp.net, css, printing

I have a requirement to print only part of a page. I cannot use css(media=print) to do this since I have no clue what the page contains. All the html in the page is dynamically generated.

Also is there any limitation on the css properties that are recognized in Print mode. Many of my css properties like background-image are not applied on the generated preview.

Comment: if you have no clue what the page will contain, how will you know what elements to print?

1 way of doing this is get the html content using php or another server side script, and use a xml parser to only output the part you want to print.
But you'd have to know something about what you'd want to print. Like an element ID or something.

Comment: :) i know what needs to be printed...but i do not know what else the page has. i would not want to burden my server.

Let me know if there is any way by which i can do this by javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can dynamically create a css and insert or switch in your html document (see http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:5_Quick_jQuery_Tips#Switch_A_Stylesheet).

You can also define a CSS like

```
<style  type="text/css" media="screen">
    #printableButNotVisible { display:none }
    #visibleButNotPrintable { display:block }
</style>

<style type="text/css" media="print">
    #printableButNotVisible { display:block }
    #visibleButNotPrintable { display:none }
</style>
```

and add dynamically classes `"printableButNotVisible"` or `"isibleButNotPrintable"` to all elements which need be either printable or visible. You can do this for example with respect of jQuery.

You can aslo use [jqPrint](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jqPrint) plugin to print selected part of the page.